# How to pass 'this' into a Promise without caching outside?

Tags: javascript, caching, asynchronous, promise, this

I have a variable called `LangDataService.isDataReady` that is a Promise wawiting to be resolved.  Upon resolve some logic will happen.  How can I pass this into that Promise?

```
LangDataService.isDataReady.then(function () {
    this.modalOn()
});
```

I know i can cache `var self_ = this;` but I'm curious of other alternatives?

Comment: [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: I believe @Andreas is referring to the fact that `arrow functions` have a lexical-scoped `this`.

Comment: @Andreas unfortunatlly arrow functions aren't widely supported and babel will just transpile to var this_ = this;

Comment: You've asked for alternatives and this is one ;) [IE11 (and below), Safari and Konquerer](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) are the only browser not supporting arrow functions. Chrome, Firefox and IE Edge do. Therefor I would disagree with the "widely" :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
LangDataService.isDataReady.then(function () {
  this.modalOn()
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Man I swear I tried that lol.  I must have just put it in the wrong spot.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood likely you chained the `bind` call to `.then()`, not `function () {...}`.